# Pagination on React search bar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pagination, searchbar, cancellation-token

EDIT: I got something to work and updated my code. Unfortunately its only partialy working. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I would like to just display current and last page - any good suggestions to how I do that?

Furthermore, if someone can tell how to do a canceltoken, it would be a big help. Can seem to figure out how to put it there.

I am trying to make a search bar with pagination. I have been succesful in making it searchable with api, but the pagination I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Could someone please provide me an example of how I will be able to do it? I've been through tons of tutorials and blogs, youtube, github and so on already.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([] as any[]);
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(5);

    const handleClick = (event:any) => {
      setCurrentPage(Number(event.target.id));
    };

    const pages = [];
    for (let i=1; i<=Math.ceil(data.length/itemsPerPage);i++ ){
      pages.push(i);
    }

    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
    const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);

    const renderPageNumbers = pages.map(number => {

      return (
        <li key={number} onClick={handleClick}>
          {number}
        </li>
      )
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {

            try {
                const {data} = await axios.get(`https://2isz0zc3qk.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/staging/search?term=${query}`)
                setData(data.items)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [query]);


    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="search">
              <input type="text"
                     placeholder={"Search product..."}
                     className={"input"}
                     onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
                     value={query}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="results">
              {currentItems.map((value, key) => (
                  <ul className='items'>
                    <li className='item'>
                      <a href={`https://www.whiteaway.com${value.url}`} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
                        <img src={value.image} alt={value.name} />
                        <p>{value.name}</p>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              ))}
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul className="pageNumbers">
              {renderPageNumbers}
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look how it's done here using React Query:
https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/pagination

Comment: Thanks alot @nik, but is there a way to do it without using libraries?